# Plugin para manipular imagens com C#

Tags: c#

eu gostaria de saber se existe algum plugin que facilite a manipulação de imagens, por exemplo, adicionar uma foto como um componente e poder alterar escala, posição e que aceite transparencia alfa entre varias imagens que eu adicione. 
Caso eu não tenha conseguido explicar, o que eu quero é uma versão bem simples de um editor de imagem, com camadas, redimensionamento, posicionamento etc.

Comment: Existe. Era só isso que queria saber?

Comment: Preciso de provas da existência dele pra ter certeza...

Comment: @TulioCalil a existência de softwares como o editor de imagens do Windows 10 deveria ser evidência suficiente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plataforma .NET vem com bibliotecas para trabalho sobre imagens.

[Veja o *namespace* `System.Drawing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing(v=vs.110).aspx).

Em especial, veja:

- [A classe `Bitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx). Apesar do nome, ela pode ser utilizada com vários formatos de arquivo.
- [A classe `Graphics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx). Ela dá suporte a escala, rotação e translação.
- [A estrutura `Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.color(v=vs.110).aspx). Com ela você conseguirá trabalhar transparência.

Note que isso é nativo e embarcado, portanto nenhum plugin é necessário.

Existe um software chamado Paint.NET, que é algo como um Gimp feito com .NET. Antigamente seu código era aberto, então se você quiser dar uma olhada em como essas classes acima podem ser usadas, [pode dar uma olhada neste repositório](https://github.com/rivy/OpenPDN).

Comment: Valeu! Eu não sabia que o paint.net já foi código aberto! Eu to fazendo usando o Graphics mesmo, mas estou com esse problema aqui: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y23vj23ggw8 até tinha postado por aqui antes, mas não tive resposta, ai pensei em ver se existe algum plugin ou coisa assim...

Comment: *O problema é a imagem ficar piscando

Comment: @TulioCalil você pode abrir uma pergunta com o código que você usa para que a gente possa ajudar a fazer parar de piscar.